# Is there any difference across the countries to play in in Pokemon Go?

Tags: pokemon-go

Is there any difference across the countries available in Pokemon Go? By 'difference', I mean things such as Pokemon that appear, available items, or different frequency of Pokemon or items that appear.

If there is any difference, can I travel for another country to catch them up **using the same account and Apple ID that I downloaded the app from**?

Comment: Other than the currency in the ingame shop probably not. It varies between regions, not countries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use your account in any country and it will be the same. Different type of locations increase the chance of seeing certain Pokemon. For example water Pokemon are more common around areas with water.

So far there haven't been any confirmations about some Pokemon only showing up in some countries. It's very well possible that this will be added in the future.

Comment: Thanks. I haven't played it yet, but I found a picture that Squirtle does appear in a desert... it's crazy! Then can you play it in another country that Pokemon Go isn't available yet, such as China or Japan?

Comment: You can. The world is fully fleshed out and filled with the Stops and gyms. Apparently the locations greatly resemble the previous AR game the company released, so I imagine the data is crowdsourced from there.

Source: Currently playing in Finland, where the game isn't technically out yet.

Answer (score 1):

I live in Munich and have the same experience as stated above for Berlin.  HOWEVER, this weekend I am in Athens and this place is absolutely overrun with Evans, Manley, and Cubone (which I have almost never seen in Munich). I have seen VERY few pudge years and absolutely no Drowsee or Rattata. Perhaps things do vary with country.

Answer (score 0):

While there doesn't seem to be real proof (yet?) it is starting to look like a few pokemons will only appear in certain parts of the world. E.g. [this article](http://www.eurogamer.net/articles/2016-07-28-pokemon-go-region-exclusive-pokemon-locations-how-and-where-to-catch-tauros-kangaskhan-mr-mime-and-farfetchd) says:

> Tauros, Kangaskhan, Mr. Mime and Farfetch'd are the Pokémon in question, and the prevailing thought now is that these four are region-locked to specific locations.

Answer (score 0):

I am level 24, live in Berlin.  The most common pokemon here are Drowzee, Pidgey Rattata etc. I have never seen a Kangaskhan in walking around in Berlin or occupying any gym here.

I just got back from Australia where I caught at least 10 Kangaskhan.  I did not see any Drowzee for the 2 weeks that I was in Australia.